# How to have git disregard unstaged changes on a post/pre-commit hook

Tags: git, testing, githooks

I am trying to do the *commit should pass all tests to succeed* automation in my rails project.
The problem is that I use `git add --patch` quite a lot before I commit and I want my tests to only run on the staged changes.

**Solution 1:**
do a `git stash --keep-index` on the pre-commit or a simple `git stash` on the post commit, followed by the hook (`rake tests`) and `git stash pop`.
This means that I'll have to wait for it to finish and while it runs, I won't have access to my unstaged changes.

**Solution 2:** I setup a new local repo (the tester) and setup the post-commit hook from the first repo (the development) to push to the tester repo. The tester repo should have a post-receive hook to run the tests and inform me (via email or whateva) whether it passes or fails to fix the commit before I push.

The second solution sounds much better (I guess) even though there will be differences on the repos due to ignored files.

**Do you have another solution to propose?**

Comment: Similar problem with me. I prefer Sol. 1 (although speed won't allow it) but there is a problem with untracked files. If I add a new class and use it but don't commit it, then the tests will run with it but the commit will be a fail. Git supports stash --include-untracked but not at version 1.7.4.1, which I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally resorted in *Solution 2* which then evolved into a mini continuous testing system.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at git-new-workdir (you can find it in the git repository contrib/workdir). It creates a new working directory you can use to run the tests.